# Webpack Fabric external is resolving to undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm setting up a project (typescript, webpack) with a couple of js libraries, configured as externals in webpack. They should not be part of the bundle, instead provided by script tags within the html.

But when trying to use them in my class, they resolve to undefined.

### Fabric configured as an external in webpack is resolving to undefined

> An error occurs when trying to set up the fabric js library as an external within a (typescript + webpack ) project. Fabric should not be bundled in the output file since it will be the responsibility of the consumer to provide (eg. through a browser script tag).

Note: jQuery initially had an issue (as an external) but is now resolved, and works as expected. Fabric on the other hand does not.

fabric has been configured as an external so that it will not be included in the webpack bundle.

Here's how...

1. Added as an external within the webpack.config.js

```
...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    fabric: 'fabric',
  },
...
```

2. Installed the declaration files for both libraries

```sh
npm install @types/jquery -D
npm install @types/fabric -D
```

3. Added the libraries in public folder and index.html (since they must not be part of the app bundle)

```
  <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

4. Created a class App.ts, imported and implemented instances of these two libraries. (see App.ts)

```
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import $ from 'jquery';
```

fabric resolves to undefined within the class App.ts with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Canvas' of undefined
```

---

Please don't recommend ProvidePlugin or installing Babel.

More about webpack "externals": https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

---

### Update #1

jQuery is now working as an external library. I was not referencing the actual jquery global "jQuery" in the externals setup. I had "JQuery" (with a capital J). That's now resolved and jquery is working. Thanks @Aluan

Fabric on the other hand seems to be a different issue altogether.

Comment: `JQuery` is a misspelling. jquery, loaded via a script tag creates no such global variable. It is named `jQuery`.

Comment: That's right! jquery was resulting in undefined due to this. Thanks! I updated to "jQuery" in the externals setup and its working. Now we have one issue, fabric is returning: "Cannot read property 'fabric' of undefined"

Comment: I don't know what the fabric library names its global but I expect the issue is similar. Also, you should probably be using `import fabric from 'fabric';` instead of trying to used named import syntax for something like that.

Comment: The fabric library names itself "fabric" under the global window object.

Comment: And if I install fabric as a project dependancy (npm install fabric), it works. But I don't want it to be part of the bundle. Hence the reason why I need to configure it as an external

Comment: Try `import fabric from 'fabric';`, log it in app.js, and see what it is

Comment: I tried that before but I get the error: "TS2339: Property 'Canvas' does not exist on type 'typeof import". The fabric library has recommended to use this syntax for importing. It's setup to be imported this way. Can you run the repo and try for your self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue with fabric is from fabric itself! The reason fabric is resolving to undefined (when being configured as an external on webpack) is related to the way that fabric exposes its library for consumption. It's an issue they need to fix.

I've added an issue on the official [fabric github page](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6552)

But there is a quick solution for us. Just import using CommonJS like this:

```
const fabric = require('fabric');
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `shimming`. Webpack docs cover this extensively here:  https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Edit to add example:

In your `webpack.config.js` `plugins` array:

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
```

EDIT:
I pulled down your code and got it working. Here are the steps:

1. `ts-loader` chokes on shims, so use babel's `@babel/preset-typescript` -- otherwise you'll need to find a way to tell the ts compiler to ignore them. This will get you started:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript core-js@3
```

2. In your root, create a file called `.babelrc` and add the following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "67",
            "safari": "11.1"
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "corejs": "3"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

3. Add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    new ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      fabric: "fabric"
    })
  ]
```

4. Also update `ts-loader`, changing it to `babel-loader`.
5. Now in your code, you'll need to prefix your shimmed libraries with `window`:

```
    constructor(private readonly selector: string, canvasHeight: number, canvasWidth: number) {
      
      window.$(`#${selector}`).replaceWith(`<canvas id="${selector}" height=${canvasHeight} width=${canvasWidth}> </canvas>`);

      this.canvas = new window.fabric.Canvas(`${selector}`, { selection: false });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am asking for something different. Did you look at the repo? ProvidePlugin (or shimming) does not solve this problem. For some reason fabric is resolving to undefined when configured as an external in webpack. How do I get fabric (and jquery) to work in my class as externals?

Comment: @ Jay, I've installed the declaration files for these libraries (ie. @types/jquery and @types/fabric) to give the type definitions, not their raw implementation src files. That should come from the files loaded via the script tags. Did you run the repo?

Comment: Oops, prematurely submitted. Externals does something different from what you're trying to accomplish. externals simply prevents a node_module from being bundled while adding a name to the ref. It won't work with embedded scripts. Did you read the docs for shimming?

Comment: I'll take a look in a bit. I'm on my mobile and AFK.

Comment: externals is precisely what I need. What you've explained about externals is spot on and IS what I am after. I need to prevent the compiler from adding the module to the bundle, and loading it from another source (ie. externally). Btw, the jquery library is working externally now (see comments above). Just the fabric library has an issue. Please do run the repo when you get the chance,

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But this is not a good solution. You didn't need to install babel, babel-loader, .babelrc, ProvidePlugin... etc You didn't need all that just to append the global object "window" to access the libraries :) Just add window and it will work anyway. But that's never good coding practice. I need to solve this issue by importing the packages I need.  jquery now works, it's just fabric that is still not working. Please don't recommend ProvidePlugin. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.